# ReferenceError: lecturer not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am working a node js CRUD operation  with mongoose and express that requires I show The details of a certain person in the database whenever I run the app, I get the following error.

ReferenceError: C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\views\show.ejs:5
    3|

```
4|  <div>
```

> > 5|      <%= lecturers.designation %>

```
6|      <div><%= lecturers.lect_id %></div>

7|      <div><%= lecturers.full_name %></div>

8|      <div><%= lecturers.gender %></div>
```

lecturers is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:549:12), :22:26)
    at returnedFn (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:580:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:223:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:437:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\app.js:63:8
    at C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3930:16
    at _init (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2007:5)
    at model.Document.init (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:370:5)
    at completeOne (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1993:12)
    at Immediate. (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1520:11)
    at Immediate. (C:\Users\Mussa\Desktop\TimeTable\v2 - Copy\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:119:16)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)

Here I my code on Line 63 That displays the error.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var secret = require("./config/secret");
var Lecturers = require("./models/lecturers").Lecturer;

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//Connects to the databse
mongoose.connect(secret.database, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else {
        console.log("Successfully Connected to the Database");
    }
});

//Called direcctly by assigning app
require("./routes/main")(app);


//INDEX
app.get("/lecturers", function(req, res){
    Lecturers.find({}, function(err, foundLecturers){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render("index", {lecturers: foundLecturers});
        }
    });
});


//CREATE
app.get("/lecturers/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("new");
});

//CREATE ROUTE
app.post("/lecturers", function(req, res){
    Lecturers.create(req.body.lecturer, function(err, lecturers){
        if(err){
            res.render("new");
        }else{
            res.redirect("/lecturers");
        }
    });
});


//SHOW ROUTE
app.get("/lecturers/:id", function(req, res){
    Lecturers.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundLecturer){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/lecturers");
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render("show", {lecturer, foundLecturer});
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my Lecturer Model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var lecturersSchema = new Schema({
    designation: { type: String },
    lect_id: { type: String, unique: true, trim: true},
    full_name: { type: String},
    gender: { type: String}
});

var Lecturer = mongoose.model("Lecturer", lecturersSchema);


module.exports = {Lecturer: Lecturer}
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like you are passing `lecturers` and trying to access `lecturer` in your view. just a typo maybe. also if you are passing an array of `lecturers` then you will have to loop through that array to display it

Comment: Thanks alot, I tried changing my view to lecturers but still got the response that "lecturers was not defined". I make edit above.

Comment: hey @Xcode, sorry actually I did not see your complete code before. You were right, it should be `lecturer` in your ejs file (view). And I found another typo in your show route. It should be `res.render("show", {lecturer: foundLecturer});` instead of `res.render("show", {lecturer, foundLecturer});`. Use `:` and not `,`

Comment: Thanks alot @Harshal Gangurde. I observed I made the mistake of using "," instead of ":"